# Python Toolbox Illegal List value

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, parameters

I updating one of the parameters in my ArcGIS Python toolbox with data from SQL Server, but am getting an illegal list value error. I have removed a lot of the 'special' characters, but am thinking there should be a list of what constitues an 'Illegal list value'. Does anyone know?

> ERROR  Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 276, in
>   updateParameters ValueError: FilterObject: illegal list value

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  When precisely do you see this error?  I suspect that we may need you to post a test Python toolbox ([code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) equivalent for Python Toolbox question) that can be copy/pasted to run and see what you are describing.

Answer (score 2):

It had nothing to do with special characters, but there was a NULL value in the column which was causing the error. After removing this row in the database, I was able to update the parameter list.